# How I keep iPhone continuous vibrating when receives remote notification?

Tags: ios, iphone, vibration

I want to keep my iPhone app vibrating when receives remote notification as my app is closed or my iPhone is closed.

I can play a special sound when receives remote notification, someone said vibrate is also a sound, use "kSystemSoundID_Vibrate" , but I still don't know how to use it.

The server can post apns like this:

```
{"aps":{
    "alert":"Receive Jane's call",
    "badge":1,
    "sound":"Opening.m4r"}
}
```

But I want to know how I add constant 'kSystemSoundID_Vibrate' to the apns, so my iPhone can play sound and vibrate continuously.